# Overlay curves on top of mesh

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, bezier-curves

Let's say you're following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nn7mISvVzJk but the curves get lost inside the mesh.

Is there a way to always see the curves on top of the mesh, kinda how bones can be seen when posing?

Comment: Hi. Please don't make answering your question rely on watching a video tutorial. Explain the issue through words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's the same as for the armature, select your curve, go in the *Properties panel > Object > Viewport Display*, enable the *In Front* option:

[image]